# How to avoid user consent in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have integrated Google Drive API with Salesforce. But I would like to avoid "USER CONSENT" manually. Instead I am looking for providing access through REST API. Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

All applications that access the data of a Google account must obtain the user's consent. It is possible via the Google Apps Marketplace for an admin to grant access for all the user's in their domain, but still some sort of consent is required.